# Make private branches with git

Tags: git, version-control

I'm somewhat new to Git.
So, my task is to make 3 branches, for 3 developers, that would connect only to their branch and work only with their own branch.
Something like this:

```
developer 1 == branch 1
developer 2 == branch 2
```

Any help or tutorials will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just should do this:

developer 1: `git checkout branch1`

developer 2: `git checkout branch2`

developer 3: `git checkout branch3`

So they will use their own branches. `push` will be only to branches that they are checkouted.

But they can use another branch, if they want. So, if you want to deny them to use another branch, just create separate repository for every developer.

Comment: thanks. How do i set the username on every branch ? Commits must be from branch user. Ex: Author of commits from branch1 must be user1, from branch2 -> user2

Comment: they should `checkout` to their branch and their commits will be to their branch only. When they use `checkout branch_name` and then `push` to remove server, branch will be created

Answer (score 3):

All branches created with Git are initially private, and trunk is essentially a branch. What you are describing is the default behaviour of Git.

Take a look [at this article](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison) on how branch handling differs in Git. Also, [this tutorial](http://git-scm.com/course/svn.html#branch) is useful for people migrating from Subversion to Git.

Comment: +1. When you clone a repository, you have a local copy of it. Everything you do there is private unless you explicitely push it to a public repository.

Comment: The git wiki article you refer to has a lot of mistakes when comparing svn and git. Branching-related paragraph is not an exception according to http://svnvsgit.com/

Comment: @bahrep admittedly that wiki page was written back in 2012 (when this question was asked) and is likely to be somewhat out of date - both VCS' have moved on since. However, I'm inclined not to reference svnvsgit.com since 1) It doesn't clearly outline the differences between Git/SVN and 2) most of the points reference dubious first-hand research that I've not been able to verify. I can confirm I cannot create a branch within 0.093 seconds using our own Subversion repository, as is claimed here: http://svnvsgit.com/#branch-creation-benchmarks.

Comment: @seanhodges 1. even in 2012 or even 2010 there were no such problems as the one described in this wiki page. 2. I tried and could reproduce the stuff about repo size and branches on my local svn repo.

Comment: @seanhodges **> most of the points reference dubious first-hand research that I've not been able to verify.** At the same time you refer to a wiki page with some benchmarks you shouldn't be able to verify as well and is based on some private email thread.

Comment: @bahrep I disagree, many of the problems with Subversion described in that wiki were very real problems for the company I worked for. Time taken to create local feature branches was one of our primary reasons for migrating some projects to Git. Few companies use Subversion locally and there was (at the time at least) no reliable way to sync a local repository with a remote one - most suggestions were to use git-svn or SVK (which we found slower than Git).

Comment: @bahrep Admittedly the Git wiki page could use some clearing up, as a VisualSVN employee perhaps you can offer your services? I also prefer that I know the source of the wiki material, svnvsgit.com goes as far as to mask WHOIS entry to hide the true author.

Comment: @seanhodges `svn copy ^/myproj/trunk ^/calc/branches/myfeature` is instant operation in SVN. But you are right, *local* branches is indeed a problem with SVN, there are no local branches or shelves so far. :( BTW, I made a comment on the page's talk section some time ago: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Talk:GitSvnComparison#Pointing_out_mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't contain any access control by itself.

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/) is a Git server, which offers access control including setting access for distinct branches.

Comment: ok, thanks for you answer.
but i can  make clone on my localhost only to one branch, right ?

Comment: If the answer was helpful you can upvote/mark the question as resolved by ticking the mark below voting buttons.

Comment: Also, I wonder if setting access right to branches is the right way to work in a small team. Are these constraints really neccessary?

Comment: i don't think so, my task is to make 3 branches, foreach developer, and every developer must work only with his branch

Comment: I don't like this idea. When working with Git you are supposed to easily create branches when you start working on major features. Setting one specified branch for every developer is somewhat crippling Git. Of course, you can allow in Gitolite using any number of branches as long as they are prefixed with developer's name, but that still leaves you with this strange orgnization. Maybe the developers are working on completely unrelated code and you want to create separate repositories instead?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on git workflow, either in http://progit.org or in http://sethrobertson.github.com/GitBestPractices

As seanhodges suggested, by default when each developer clones the upstream repo, they will have a private version of the branches, eg master.  They can do whatever they want locally. When they are ready to share with other people, they push/pull/etc.  There is no particular reason why they need to be on a branch named "dev1".  If other people want to look at their stuff, they can by adding the dev's repo as a remote and then they can look at dev1/master.

If you want to do it they way you suggested, you of course can.  Just `git checkout $USER`.  People find it more useful to make feature branches (a branch for a particular feature) than user branches.

If you are talking access control, then sure gitolite is probably the best bet as mentioned in the other answer, but really there is no reason why you need to bother except in the most formal circumstances.  If a user screws something up, you can always blow those changes away or restore to an earlier state.